# JS file can't find certain HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a file (main.js) that seems to load certain element after some time. How do I make it so that all html elements are loaded and ready to be manipulated by main.js?

On my screen, the console will print = 
"initiated false" then
"initiated version true"

index.html

```
<head>
<!-- JQUERY, BOOTSTRAP -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-slider.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validator.min.js"></script>

<!-- MAIN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navbar.css">
</head>
<body onload="$('#connection_show').fadeIn(SHOW_BODY_MS)">
<!-- HEADER -->
<div id="header" class="page-header">
    <script>
        $("#header").load("header.html");
    </script>
</div>

<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <script>
        $("#navbar").load("navbar.html");
    </script>
</nav>
etc...
```

header.html

```
<label class="inline margin-left-20">System Version:</label><p id="systemVersion" class="inline">Unavailable</p></a>    
<label class="inline">Background Calls:</label>
<input id="intervalCtrl" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" data-width="70" data-on="On" data-off="Off" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
```

main.js

```
function getAndDisplayVersion(){
$.ajax({
    url: VERSION_URL,
    type: "GET"
}).done(function(data) {
    $("#systemVersion").html(data["system"]);
    console.log("initiated version", $("#intervalCtrl").length > 0)
});
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getAndDisplayVersion);

function registerIntervalChangeHandler() {
    console.log("initiated ", $("#intervalCtrl").length > 0)    
    $("#intervalCtrl").bootstrapToggle();
    $("#intervalCtrl").change(function() {
        console.log("registered!")
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", registerIntervalChangeHandler);
```

I have changed the order the functions are called and it doesn't make a difference ("initiated version true" will always print last even though the function comes first).

Comment: When I try your code, I get `initiated version true` followed by `initiated  true`. You must not be registering your scripts in the correct locations. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code seems to work properly. OP must need to reorganize locations of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The `#intervalCtrl` element is part of the `header.html` file which mean that it is entirely possible for the `DOMContentLoaded` event to be triggered before this element is added to the page (it is added using jQuery's `.load()` function).

The [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method accepts a callback function as the second parameter.
You could use that to run some code once the html file was loaded.

Here is an example:

```
$("#navbar").load("navbar.html", function(){
    getAndDisplayVersion();
    registerIntervalChangeHandler();
});
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! I agree, people on stack overflow seem to love downvoting.

Comment: @purry I'm glad I could help. If this answered your question don't forget to mark it using the tick in the top left corner.